# JSF component for Gantt chart

Tags: jsf, charts, components

I need a JSF component for representing Gantt chart. Does any component library (like RichFaces) contain such a component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) has a Gantt chart and [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) has an image component which allows you to dynamically stream content in. [Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf) is an example in combination with JFreeChart.

Alternatively you can also just grab `h:graphicImage` and let it point to a simple servlet which streams the `JFreeChart` result to the response based on the request parameters or pathinfo.

Comment: Actually it's not a problem to show the image. But I don't get it how to get the image from JFreeChart.

Comment: Oh, I've googled something related, maybe this is what I want.

Comment: Make it to return the image in flavor of an `InputStream` somehow ;) Google "JFreeChart Developer Guide" for the devguide PDF (which actually isn't freeware).

Comment: Yeah, it costs 40$. But I think I've found well enough tutorial to sort it out by myself.

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) does it.
See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartGanttDemo1.htm) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of PrimeFaces include a [timeline component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/basic.xhtml).

Events in the [custom example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/custom.xhtml) have end dates, which makes the events to be rendered as bars.

Though it is not full blown [Gantt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart), it could be enough for certain projects.

Comment: Yes, but the 'relation' between 'tasks' is not available in this so it is kind of a (imo very) limited Ghant chart

Comment: True, it is not full blown Gantt, but it could be enough for certain projects.

Comment: True, hence no downvote ;-) And maybe PF can enhance it (or the component they use) in so it **is** supported